# Is there such a thing as a SECURE client side password encryption?

Tags: encryption, passwords, client-side

Client side encrption of user password->>

I have searched for an answer to my question on this site but there is nothing specific to my question and was wondering if someone could shed some ligth.

*THE QUESTION***
Would it be possible (and secure) if I was to encript a user password on the client side by using the user entered password on the login form as the passsword for the encrpted file, then send file to server side. The only way that this file can be decypted would be with an administrative password (second password) which only the server side knows meaning that not even the user is able to decypt it.

As an example - say i encrpt a password using the user entered form password in winrar. the winrar file gets sent to the server. Now for the server to decrpt and get the password it needs to use its unique server side decypting password.

Or perhaps, instead of using the user entered password to decrypt - get say Javascript to produce a once of random() password?

I'm not that advanced in web development and only have loggic to go off and hope that somone who is can give me some pointers on the flaws of this approach?

Comment: I believe reading up on [asymmetric encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) would be enlightening.

Comment: **Never encrypt passwords**.  Instead, use one-way hash functions.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use HTTPS and SSL, this is inherently insecure, since an attacker can pre-emptively replace your Javascript with malicious Javascript that sends the user's password to an evil server, then does everything else normally.

Comment: Even SSL doesn't seem the most secure these days ;-)

Comment: @pst - SSL is secure.  It is just certain SSL implementations / deployments that are insecure.  (But then again, it is possible to create an insecure implementation of ANY security system ... if you don't understand it, or are not careful enough in coding it and/or deploying it.)

Comment: @StephenC: Mostly, CAs are insecure.

Answer (score 1):

Using one password to encrypt and a different password to decrypt is called [Public-key Cryptography (PKI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

But if you do use it, then there is no need to send the encryption key to the server as a "public" key used to encrypt the data and only a "private" key can decrypt it.

Implementing PKI in Javascript would be a big project.

You might want to re-phrase your question, it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Javascript RSA implementations exist; I've used them.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your password as a one way hash (ie MD5). Then on the client side, MD5 the password input and send that to the db..

Comment: **No**; not MD5.  Also, unsalted hashes are evil.  Finally, that's vulnerable to replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signing/